# Oracle SQL query that extracts data from a point today and future point of tomorrow

Tags: oracle

I have an sql that I need to be able to pull data from 4am today through 4am tomorrow.  I need the data to show hourly production as the operation runs from 4am until 1:30AM  I am having trouble putting the logic in that recognizes the rollover at midnight.  This needs to pull the dates automatically and not manually putting in the date. Essentially:

```
where mod_date_time >= trunc(sysdate) + 4/24
and mod_date_time <= trunc(sysdate)+1 + 3/24 + 59/24*60
```

Thank you

Comment: "through 4am tomorrow" and "until 1:30AM" contradict each other. Please make up your mind, and then let us know what you decided. Then: for the second inequality, use strict inequality, which will make life easier: `<trunc(sysdate) + 1 + 4/24'` And, in any case, why would you add 59 minutes to that? Did you mean `+3/24 + 59/24*60`? (And obviously you are missing parentheses around 24*60 - third grade arithmetic!) Other than that, what difficulty do you find with "the rollover at midnight" (whatever "rollover" may mean)?

Comment: The shift runs from 4am to 130am but due to potential OT I have to capture all data from 4am to 4am.  As for the second point, it was meant to be 3/24 + 59/24*60.  So you know, it works just fine without the parentheses, I use that equation in other sql's.  The problem with the rollover is that once midnight hits, the dates will adjust; if I need 11/28 4am to midnight and 11/29 midnight until 4am it will only pull 4am to midnight for the current sysdate since there is no data for it pull sysdate+1 midnight to 4am.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy to do with intervals ...

```
 where mod_date_time >= trunc(sysdate) + to_dsinterval('0 4:0:0') -- 4:00am today
 and  mod_date_time <= trunc(sysdate) + to_dsinterval('1 4:0:0') -- 4:00am tomorrow
```

... except for this snag:

> The problem with the rollover is that once midnight hits, the dates will adjust

So you can't use SYSDATE in this query without an anchor. Do you have a column which represents shift day or start time? You can use that instead:

```
  where mod_date_time >= trunc(shift_start_date) + to_dsinterval('0 4:0:0') -- 4:00am today
 and  mod_date_time <= trunc(shift_start_date) + to_dsinterval('1 4:0:0') -- 4:00am tomorrow
```

Alternatively, you could just run the query in historical mode:

```
 where mod_date_time >= trunc(sysdate-1) + to_dsinterval('0 4:0:0') -- 4:00am today
 and  mod_date_time <= trunc(sysdate) + to_dsinterval('0 4:0:0') -- 4:00am tomorrow
```